# Cannot read property '$options' of undefined making external js file for head options

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I need to set up global head in Nuxt for my app, which some subpages will overwrite. Those global head needs to contain translated data.

I created `seoHead.js` file with code:

```
import Vue from "vue";

export const $t = (sign) => Vue.prototype.$nuxt.$options.i18n.t(sign);

export default {
  title: $t("seoGlobal.title"),
  meta: [
    { charset: "utf-8" },
    { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
    {
      hid: "description",
      name: "description",
      content: $t("seoGlobal.description"),
    },
    {
      hid: "ogSiteName",
      name: "og:site_name",
      content: "Test Page",
    },
    {
      hid: "ogTitle",
      name: "og:title",
      content: $t("seoGlobal.ogTitle"),
    },
    (...)
  ],
};
```

I import and use this data in my `index.vue` and other pages like this:

```
import seoHead from "~/constants/seoHead";

export default {
  head() {
    const metaI18n = this.$nuxtI18nSeo();
    const currentPath = process.env.LP_URL + this.$router.currentRoute.fullPath;
    return {
      ...seoHead,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: "ogLocale",
          name: "og:locale",
          content: metaI18n.meta[0].content,
        },
        {
          hid: "ogLocaleAlternate",
          name: "og:locale:alternate",
          content: metaI18n.meta[1].content,
        },
        {
          hid: "ogUrl",
          name: "og:url",
          content: currentPath,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
(...)
```

Unfortunately, I am facing `Cannot read property '$options' of undefined` error. It's strange for me, because I already used `export const $t = (sign) => Vue.prototype.$nuxt.$options.i18n.t(sign);` code in another js file. Anyone know why this error appears? You know the best way to translate global head options?

Comment: I'm not too acquainted with Nuxt, but your error messages seems to indicate a race condition: `seoHead` is used before Nuxt's setup is complete, so `$nuxt` has not been defined (injected) yet when it is accessed in `$t`. Can you rule out that this is the case here?

Comment: @dr_barto It could be. I'm not so experienced in Nuxt lifecycle :/

Comment: Please check if you import `seoHead.js` somewhere else, and try to remove that import if you find any. It's unlikely, but .. well :)

Comment: Only in described file I imported `seoHead.js`

Comment: Maybe this workaround works for you: delay the execution of `$t` by changing `seoHead.js` to export a function which simply returns the object you are currently exporting. Then, in `index.vue`, just change the line `...seoHead` to `...seoHead()`.

Comment: @dr_barto It works

Comment: @dr_barto Can You give your response as answer, not comment? So I will sign It as problem resolver and You will get bouty :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, there seems to be a timing issue with the Nuxt lifecycle and your component: at the time your component `seoHead.js` is imported, Nuxt has not yet injected its `$nuxt` object into `Vue`. So an easy workaround would be to delay the execution of your `$t` function (which accesses `$nuxt`):

1. Change your component to export a function which returns the object, instead of directly exporting the object:

```js
export default function() {
  return {
    title: $t("seoGlobal.title"),
    // ...
  }
}
```

2. In `index.vue`, change your `head` function to call `seoHead` when spreading it:

```js
return {
  ...seoHead(),
  // ...
```

This way, the code which accesses `$nuxt` will be executed later -- not when `seoHead` is imported, but only when the `head` function is executed. At this time, the Nuxt lifecycle hopefully has finished its startup work and the required object is in place.

---

As I said, this is merely a workaround; if you would be calling `head` immediately in `index.vue`, the same error would appear. So unless you find out a proper way to integrate into the Nuxt lifecycle, I suggest to also put a safeguard into your translation function:

```js
const $t = (sign) => Vue.prototype.$nuxt 
  ? Vue.prototype.$nuxt.$options.i18n.t(sign)
  : sign
```

This will return the i18n key if the required infrastructure is not yet in place. Not great, but better than an exception ;)

Alternatively you might be able to directly import your i18n functionality, without going through Nuxt at all; this way you wouldn't have any dependency on the infrastructure at all -- much better.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you basically need here is a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

```js
export default {
  title: $t("seoGlobal.title"),
  meta: this.computedMeta,
  computed:{
    computedMeta(){
      return [....] // this contains the array of objects in meta
   }
  }
  methods:{
   yourMethod(sign){
     return this.$nuxt.$options.i18n.t(sign);
   }
  }
};
```

then just import it as a mixin in whatever file you need.